# How to include a dependency inside an Android library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Currently i'm writing a library for android that needs Volley to function. Currently, the Volley dependency is declared in both the dependencies block for the library and whatever app uses the library. What do I need to do so that my Library can pull in its needed dependencies itself, instead of having the implementing app also declaring the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle supports transitive dependencies.

For a local library, this works like this:

```
compile(project(:LIBRARY_NAME)) {
    transitive=true
}
```

For remote libraries:

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0'){
    transitive=true //default, normally no need to specify explicitly
}
```

Comment: What if the library is a `.jar`?

Comment: jars need to be shipped with a `pom.xml` (which is the maven way) if stored remotely.

Comment: The jar is sitting locally in the apps /libs/ folder.

Comment: You can't include transitive dependencies from single jar files, as these do not include this information. You should either reference the module directly or upload your library to a local or remote repository with the required information.

Comment: Ah, thats too bad. I will see if storing it remote is a viable option. Thanks!