# Android library seems not to include it's dependencies (forcing me to add those dependencies in the app module)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an Android library and a demo app that uses it. up until now I compiled both the app and the lib via source code and now that Iv'e built the lib and want to use the AAR file instead of the lib's source code - I get error about missing classes during runtime.

It looks like the dependencies of the library are not included in the AAR file.
Exception description:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
....<clinit>(....java:57) at ...onCreate(...java:65) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5961) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) ...
```

Here is the application's build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def APP_VERSION = 1.0

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName APP_VERSION + "(" + appVersionCode + ")"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        //pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'library_filename', ext:'aar')

    <HERE IV'E ADDED THE LIB'S DEPENDENCIES IN ORDER FOR THE APP TO WORK>

    //Other dependencies needed by the application
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'

}
```

In this example it happened with Log4J. When I added the dependency of Log4J from the library's build.gradle to the application's build.gradle - the error did not happen.

The library is a simple one. We are using flavors and multiDexEnabled is set to true.

Any ideas why the lib's dependencies are not found when building with the AAR file? any remedies?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your app gradle file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a dependency inside an Android library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877345/how-to-include-a-dependency-inside-an-android-library)

Comment: marking the dependencies as transitive doesn't seem to help. after trying to build and run the app again - it still crashes. I can also see that the size of the library aar file hasn't changed (I would expect it to grow).

Comment: An AAR file has no transitive dependencies. Nor does a JAR file. What powers transitive dependencies is the metadata associated with the AAR/JAR in an artifact repository. You are not using an artifact repository for this library, and so you have no metadata.

Comment: So what meta data should I add to make it transitive? can you give an example or instructions? we have and artifact repository that we can utilize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aar file **doens't contain** the transitive dependencies.

The alternative is to publish the library in a **maven repository** (public or private). Gradle in this case with the pom file is able to download also the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's inline with the little research Iv'e done about this subject yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

To create a self-contained jar (fat jar) you can look into solutions like jarjar(https://github.com/shevek/jarjar).

Comment: Links are fine, but please consider adding an example in the answer as well.